# How do I keep my UTF8 characers when sending email?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, plsql

Oracle 11g. PL/SQL. Oracle uses AL32UTF8.

```
LastName
--------
Manaña
```

The unicode value in Oracle for the ñ is (00F1) the ascii value is (0241). When I send this value in an email. The email reads 'manan?a'. 
The email value in HEX is (3F).

**Question: How can I keep my 'ñ' when I send it via email?**

Here's select dump:

```
  select dump(last_name) => [Typ=1 Len=7: 77,97,110,97,195,177,97]
```

When I send the email, I call package.mail
Here's that snippet

```
 last_name := 'Manaña'
 packagename.mail(recipient ==>'emailrecipeint@blah.com',
                    subject ==>'Email Subject',
                    message ==>last_name);

PROCEDURE mail(sender     IN VARCHAR2 default 'non-reply@company.edu',
   recipients IN VARCHAR2,
   subject    IN VARCHAR2,
   message    IN VARCHAR2) IS
   conn utl_smtp.connection;
   userid varchar2(256);
    globalname varchar2(256);
  BEGIN    
    conn := begin_mail(sender, recipients, subject);
    select global_name into globalname from global_name;
    select user into userid from dual;
    write_text(conn, message);
    end_mail(conn);
   END;
```

Here's the snippet for **package.write_text**

```
    PROCEDURE write_text(conn    IN OUT NOCOPY utl_smtp.connection,
                         message IN VARCHAR2) IS
    BEGIN  
     utl_smtp.write_data(conn, message);
    END;
```

Comment: What does `select dump(lastName) from your_table where <<predicate to return this row>>` return?  How are you sending email?  `UTL_MAIL`?  `UTL_SMTP`?  Something else?  Can you show us the code that sends your emails (particularly the piece where you specify the encoding)?

Comment: The Spanish word is mañana (-:

Comment: Can you post the `write_text` procedure as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail is fundamentally 7-bit. To send anything else than 7-bit text/plain, encapsulate and encode it using MIME. In your case, it's probably sufficient to delclare `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`. Then if course you need to QP-encode your text; your language probably has a library for this. (It's not hard to roll your own, but it's usually a bad idea.)